# jQuery Datepicker - de-emphasize (not disable) past dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to gray out past dates in the jquery ui datepicker, but letting the user able to select them.

The only thing that allow something similar is the option `minDate: 0`, but it's designed to completely disable past dates.
Jquery doesn't even mark them with a different class to simply apply a different style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `beforeShowDay` callback function?

Here is a quick sample: https://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/wnenpfpx/

---

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay  : function(date) 
       {
          var today = new Date();
          var isToday = (today>date);
          if(isToday) return [true, 'myClass', 'Some caption (if needed)']; 
          else return [true, '', '']; //default ... you can pass false to disable this date
        },
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. As it is takes in consideration today too because the <code>date</code> object has no time while <code>Date()</code> does. I'm trying to modify it using ISO 8601 to compare the dates.

Comment: it worked perfectly. Now I've got a new idea but I need to manipulate the html inside any day's a tag. It is possible?

Comment: @Fehu Can you give me one example of what is that you wish to accomplish? Only certain days or each one on calendar? Please give me example .. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var d = date.getTime();
        if (d < new Date()) {
            return [true, 'myClassForPastDates', ''];
        } else {
            return [true, ''];
        }
    }
});
```

In the function you have to return the class name you want to append. But you have to look up how you overwrite the default themes´ css.

http://jsfiddle.net/97L93a3h/21/